# Avoid self join and update

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a dataset like this

```
rowno   kc      id      BStart      bFinish     Perioddate  
310     48      307861  2015-01-20  2015-01-22  2015-10-10
310     48      307861  2015-01-20  2015-01-22  2016-01-16
310     48      307861  2015-01-20  2015-01-22  2016-04-23
310     48      307861  2015-01-20  2015-01-22  2016-07-30
310     48      307861  2015-01-20  2015-01-22  2016-11-05
310     48      307861  2015-01-20  2015-01-22  2019-01-13
310     48      307861  2015-01-20  2015-01-22  NULL


UPDATE m2        
  SET         
  BStart = (CASE WHEN m.BStart <= m2.BFinish and m2.BFinish <= m.Perioddate         
        THEN DATEADD(dd, 1,m.periodDate)         
    WHEN m.BStart <= m2.BFinish And m2.BFinish > m2.periodDate And m.BStart <= m.PeriodDate         
        THEN DATEADD(dd, 1,m.periodDate)        
  ELSE m.BStart END)    
  FROM #result56 AS m         
  INNER JOIN #result56 AS m2        
  ON m.ROWNO = m2.ROWNO - 1 
  and m.Kc = m2.Kc;
```

I get output from the update statement like this

```
rowno   kc      id      BStart      bFinish     Perioddate 
310     48      307861  2015-01-20  2015-01-22  2015-10-10
310     48      307861  2015-10-11  2015-01-22  2016-01-16
310     48      307861  2016-01-17  2015-01-22  2016-04-23
310     48      307861  2016-04-24  2015-01-22  2016-07-30
310     48      307861  2016-07-31  2015-01-22  2016-11-05
310     48      307861  2016-11-06  2015-01-22  2019-01-13
310     48      307861  2019-01-14  2015-01-22  NULL
```

How do i get the result using just Select without updates and without using a self join

Answer (score -1):

If you *simply* needed 'the row before' (`m.ROWNO = m2.ROWNO - 1`) then I'd suggest to use [LEAD](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213125.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396);
but since you also require `m.Kc = m2.Kc` I don't see how you want to accomplish this without a self-join to be honest.

Comment: You are not new here, that should be a comment